# button click action to close view with extjs 4

Tags: button, view, extjs4

i have a login form  when i click connect button i want to go to another view and close thhe login view.

it my souce code:

login view

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.login.LoginForm' ,{
 extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
alias : 'widget.login',

bodyStyle: "background-image:url('resources/images/logo.png')",
margin: '100 50 10 450',
width:500,
height:320,
frame: true,
initComponent: function() {
this.items= [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name : 'id',
    fieldLabel: 'id',
    hidden:true
},
{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        x:100,
        y:100,
        cls:'user',
        emptyText : "votre nom d'utilisateur...",
        fieldLabel:"Nom d'utilisateur",
        name:'j_username',



    },{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        x:100,
        y:100,
        emptyText : "votre mot de passe...",
         name:'j_password',
        fieldLabel:'Mot de passe'

    },

     {
             xtype: 'checkbox',
            boxLabel: 'Rester connecte',
            x:100,
            y:110,
            allowBlank: false},
            {xtype: 'button',
                text:'Connexion',
                action: 'connect',

                margin:'120 0 0 170',
                name:'connect'
            },


                {xtype: 'button',
                    margin:'120 20 0 20',
                    text:' Annuler ',
                    action: 'reset',
                        name:'reset',

                },
            {
                xtype: 'tbtext',
                text: 'Copyright ©  Tous droits réservés',
                margin: '64 0 0 58',

              }
    ],
this.callParent(arguments);
}


});
```

home view

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.view.login.HomePage' ,{
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',

alias : 'widget.home',

requires: [
           'Ext4Example.view.login.WestMenu',
           'Ext4Example.view.login.CenterPanel'

       ],
       layout: {
           type: 'border',
           padding: '0 5 5 5'
       },

initComponent: function() {


this.items= [

    {

    xtype: 'westmenu',
    region: 'west'
},{

    xtype: 'portletpanel',
    region: 'center',
}
],

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

my controller

```
Ext.define('Ext4Example.controller.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

stores: ['Login'],

models: ['Login'],

views: ['login.LoginForm','login.HomePage','login.CenterPanel','login.WestMenu'],


init: function() {


    this.control({
        'login button[action=add]': {  

        },

        'login button[action=reset]': {  
            'click' : function(button, event, opt) {  

                var form = button.up('form');
                form.getForm().reset();
            }  
        },

        'login button[action=connect]': {  

            'click' :this.connect
        }
    });
 },
 connect:function(button,record) 
{

var view1 = Ext.widget('home');


}
```

});

when i click on the button connect i see the two views on the same page  but i want that the login view desappear and only i want to show the home view.

any one have a solution ?

Comment: Where you created login and home view in your code. In the above code you had define but not create yet... Please have a look at that position.

Comment: i allready created the login and home view and it's mentionned here on the top

Comment: You had define login and home view but not created in above mentioned code. Please have a look over your view creating area.

Comment: thank you hariharan i fixed the error  

i add this   this.getLogin().close();

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var win = button.up('login');
win.close();
```